# Can an ally charge your Staff of the Magi before a long rest by casting a bunch of spells at you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

The [*Staff of the Magi*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi) allows you to absorb spells cast at you to replenish its charges.

Considering that the description doesn't say that it has to be cast by a hostile person, is it possible for, say, a mage in your group to just throw a bunch of high-level spells to charge the Staff almost to full?

It would be just before the group is about to take a long rest, in case the *Staff of the Magi* has pretty much exhausted everything in the last big fight.

Comment: Welcome to Rpg.SE! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour), it's a useful introduction to the site.

Answer (score 12):

### That seems to work.

As you pointed out, the Staff does not say anything about the caster being hostile:

> In addition, you can use your reaction when another creature casts a spell that targets only you.

So it should work as a storage for all your friends' unused spell slots.

**But beware!**

> However, if doing so brings the staff's total number of charges above 50, **the staff explodes** as if you activated its retributive strike.

Comment: I don't think the "your own spells" sentence is supported by the quote you provide. It explicitly states "when *another creature* casts a spell", and I can't think of a meaning for "another creature" other than "a creature which is not you".

Comment: @KamilDrakari You are absolutely right, I don't know how I missed that